# Instead of rewrite new file is created

Tags: java

I'm trying to write to a file which is already exists. As far as i have seen on forums this code should rewrite the old file but instead of rewrite it puts the file name into [] brackets and creates a new one. Any idea?

```
 try {
   File file = new File("/home/erik/glassfish3/" + selectedMss + ".ini");
   BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
   for (String newline : content) {
     output.write(newline + "\n");
   }
   output.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: if selectedMss is an array then its .toString() will have []

Comment: @ChrisC No, it won't. But if it's an `ArrayList` or other `java.util` collection, then it will.

Comment: Except for your fileName, I dont think there is any other problem!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FileWriter` class has a constructor that accepts a second boolean argument which specifies whether the writer should use append mode, which will append new content to the end of an existing file.

I would also recommend closing the writer in a `finally` block.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

```
BufferedWriter output;
try {                
    File file = new File("/home/erik/glassfish3/"+selectedMss+".ini");

    //Providing true for second argument specifies it should be appended. 
    output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));

    for(String newline: content){
        output.write(newline+"\n");      
    }

} catch ( IOException e ) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
  output.close();
}
```

Comment: How about *try with resources*?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    try 
    {
           File file = new File("/home/erik/glassfish3/" + selectedMss + ".ini");
           BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,false));
            //true to append       //false to overwrite.

           for (String newline : content) 
           {
                  output.write(newline + "\n");
           }
           output.close();
           catch (IOException e)
           {
                  e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
```

You can also check java docs for more clarification:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html